# Using click event to show response in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am following a link to allow a person to reset a password, however, everything that I have done so far isn't working and I can't figure out why as I am following the tutorial closely. I am using javascript and html so far, but there are no errors in the console so i am unsure what is wrong.

HTML

```
<div class="container-forgotPassword">
    <div class ="row justify-content-center"> 
        <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center"> 
             <img id="logologin" src="../img/logo1.png" alt="logo"/>
                <input class="formPassword" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your Email Address"> 
                <input type="button" class="btn-forgotPassword" value="Reset Password"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /container -->
```

jQuery

```
var email = $("#email");
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.btn-forgotPassword').on('click', function () {
    if (email.val() != "") {
        email.css('border', '1px solid green');

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'php/forgotPassword.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { 
                email: email.val()
            }, success: function (response) { 
                    console.log(response);
            }
        });
    } else 
        email.css('border', '1px solid red');
});
});
```

In the tutorial so far he has gotten the input box to turn green/ red and when he enters text into the input field and then clicks the button it will create a response in the console log. But as I said mine is doing nothing, does anyone know how I can fix this? Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @Andreas Didn't realise there was no quote, I fixed it there now. There are no errors in the console, I wouldn't lie

Comment: @Andreas I forgot to add the line above the function. See the edited question. On firefox, it isn't letting me click the button

Comment: Where is the script located/when is it executed? Most likely `email.length` is zero... -> Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: @Andreas It is at the bottom of the php file before the body ends. What is email.length? I don't have that in my code. I did show the actual problem. There are no errors in the console but nothing seems to be working, even though I am closely following a tutorial.

Comment: There is no way we can identify the problem with this incomplete and unverifiable example... -> Please add a [**minimal, complete and verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: @Andreas This is the entire code that I have, other than a bootstrap template. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQkhoBxyOjM&feature=youtu.be This is the tutorial I am watching and I have got to 9 minutes. I followed his code exactly, other than changing some class names so they don't clash with other CSS. I don't know what the problem is, hence why I turned to SO, as there are no errors in the console and I cannot see any errors myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need `error` callback in ajax to show you the error
2. you miss write. there is no parameter named `method` in jquery ajax. this should be `type`

.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'php/forgotPassword.php',
    type: 'POST', //not method
    dataType: 'text',
    data: { 
        email: email.val()
    }, success: function (response) { 
            console.log('success');
            console.log(response);
    }, error: function(response){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(response); //get all error response
        console.log(response.responseText);//get error responseText
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, this worked for me. Well explained on what the problem is as well, thank you :)

Comment: `method` and `type` have the same effect. Only difference is that `method` is only available in jQuery since 1.9 and above.

Comment: The `error` handler has **three** parameters. The second and third parameter are the most informative ones.